# How to detect change of complex object in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I am working on an angular project. So I have a complext style object and I bind it to my angular component.

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    style:any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.style = { 
            radius:15, 
            fill: { 
                color: "red" 
            }, 
            stroke: { 
                color: "blue", 
                width: 3 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

And my-component gets the object and use it with a third party object.

**my.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    style: any;
    thirdPartyObject: Style;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.style = new Style({
            radius: style.radius,
            fill: new Fill({ color: style.fill.color }),
            stroke: new Stroke({ color: style.stroke.color, width: style.stroke.width })
        });
    }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        thirdPartyObject.setStyle(function(){
            return this style;          
        })
    }
}
```

I am creating the third party Style object using style object that comes from app.component. And `thirdPartyObject` has a function named `setStyle()` to get the style object.

So when I change the property of style in app.component, how can I update the my-component? This binding is different.

Comment: You can make use of EventEmitter.

Comment: `how can I refresh the my-component` , what you need to update in `MyComponent`..?

Comment: @ganesh045 angular property binding fires sub component. When I change a property binded sub component, it changes immediately. But in this stuation I have a complex object. So How can I do it?

Comment: `this stuation I have a complex object` it is not about complex object or simple object. what you need update, is it child component variable from parent component or parent component variable from child component... ? may be I am unable understand your requirement properly. can you elaborate it once ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's `ChangeDetectorRef` to manually detect changes and tigger a render

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    style: any;
    thirdPartyObject: Style;

    constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.style = new Style({
            radius: style.radius,
            fill: new Fill({ color: style.fill.color }),
            stroke: new Stroke({ color: style.stroke.color, width: style.stroke.width })
        });
    }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        this.setStylesToThirdPartyObject();
    }

    setStylesToThirdPartyObject(): void {
        thirdPartyObject.setStyle(function(){
            return this style;          
        });
        this.ref.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

Read more about CDR on https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Answer (score 0):

here is a complete example for change detection in angular:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CalcComponent } from '../calc-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-circular-area',
  templateUrl: './circular-area.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./circular-area.component.scss']
})
export class CircularAreaComponent implements OnInit {
  public render: Boolean;
  public radius: number;
  public r: number;
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  **onChange**(event: any, r: number) {
    console.log(r);
    this.r = Number(r);
    this.render = true;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.render = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.render = false;
  }
}
```

---

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <form  **(change)="onChange($event,r.value)**">  
        <fieldset class="material">
          <label>Radius</label>
          <hr>
          <input #r type="number" placeholder={{radius}} autocomplete="on" value = 5 required> 
        </fieldset>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!render">
           <app-calc-component value={{r.value}} selCalc='circulararea'></app-calc-component>
      </ng-container>
      </form>
 </div>
```

The onChange-method triggers the changeDetection. See also on my git in calculate-component

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pass the style to your child component using **[`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)** class decorator, so angular can keep tracks of **`style`** object and re-render your child component when it detect a change.

In your app.component.html:

```
<your-component [style]="style"></your-component>
```

In your child component ts file, apply `setStyle` in `ngOnInit` and `ngOnChanges`:

```
 @Input() style: any;
 ngOnInit() {
   thirdPartyObject.setStyle(function() { return this.style });
 }
 ngOnChanges() {
   thirdPartyObject.setStyle(function() { return this.style });   
 }
```

And since **`style`** is an object, angular tracking it's reference, not it's property, so you have to change **`style`** by create new object (similar to changing react's state):

In your app component ts file:

```
changeStyleStroke(){
   let newStroke = {
      stroke: { 
        color: "red", 
        width: 3 
      } 
   };

   //Update style this way will trigger change detection that detect changes and re-render your component

   this.style = {...this.style, ...stroke};
 }
```